# How to see results as text or csv in Azure Data Studio without saving every time?

Tags: azure-data-studio

When running a query in Azure Data Studio I just want to see the results in text, not in a spreadsheet. Every time I have to click on the little icons in the right toolbar of the result set, then click the save as window, then save. Then finally the text appears in a new tab.

Is there a way just to see the text quickly so I can copy and paste, without having to save every time?